# Get 25 quantile in cumsum pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 4, 10, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 42, 50, 54],
              'value': [37410.0, 18400.0, 200000.0, 392000.0, 108000.0, 423000.0, 80000.0, 307950.0,
 50807.0, 201740.0, 182700.0, 131300.0, 282005.0, 428800.0, 56000.0, 412400.0, 1091595.0, 1237200.0,
 927500.0]})
```

And I do the following:

```
df.sort_values(by='id').set_index('id').cumsum()

        value
id           
2     37410.0
4     55810.0
10   255810.0
12   647810.0
13   755810.0
14  1178810.0
19  1258810.0
20  1566760.0
21  1617567.0
22  1819307.0
24  2002007.0
25  2133307.0
27  2415312.0
29  2844112.0
30  2900112.0
31  3312512.0
42  4404107.0
50  5641307.0
54  6568807.0
```

I want to know the first element of id that is bigger than 25% of the cumulative sum. In this example, 25% of the cumsum would be 1,642,201.75. The first element to exceed that would be 22. I know it can be done with a for, but I think it would be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
percentile_25 = df['value'].sum() * 0.25
res = df[df['value'].cumsum() > percentile_25].head(1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   id     value
9  22  201740.0
```

Or use [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) to do the search in *O(log N)*:

```
percentile_25 = df['value'].sum() * 0.25
i = df['value'].cumsum().searchsorted(percentile_25)
res = df.iloc[i]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
id           22.0
value    201740.0
Name: 9, dtype: float64
```